# Geting small chackbox near the main one. Rendering problems

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image: Buttons]

I think the photo is talking alone I'm using bootstrap and installed and uninstalled react strap and react bootstrap. And I'm now using bootstrap in my react project but today randomly i started to work and this appeared even when i'm copying code from the official website of bootstrap.
Code:

```js
 return (
    <div className='containerSelectMasekhtot'>
      <h1>selection part</h1>
      {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
        <div className='bookContainer  '>
          <h5 onClick={() => handleEntireBookChange(key)}>{key}</h5>
          <br />
          {value.map((arrValue, index) => (
            <div className='bookChild '>
              <input
                type='checkbox'
                id={key + index}
                name={arrValue.name}
                value={arrValue.name}
                checked={data[key][index].selected}
                onChange={() => handleOnChange(key, index)}
              />
              <label className='btn btn-outline-primary ' for={key + index}>
                {arrValue.name},{data.book1[0].name}
              </label>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Well, the photo is not talking alone as you say in your description... please explain clearly what the intended result is. What is the exact problem??? What do you want??? You've only said what you are using.